# Round Numerical Values to Nearest Multiple of 5

Tags: bash, unix, integer, rounding

I have a text file with one line of percentages. I need to round all of the numbers in the text file to the nearest integer of 5, for example...

`4` rounds up to `5`, `8` rounds up to `10`, `12` rounds down to `10`, `17` rounds down to `15`, etc...

**Text File:**

```
25% 80% 22% 67% 45% 30%
```

**Expected Rounded Output:**

```
25% 80% 20% 70% 45% 30%
```

**Attempted Code for a Single Integer:**

```
m=23 | (( m /= 5, m *= 5 )) && echo $m
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Please see latest edit

Comment: Please note that `67` shouldn't become `70` as nearest number would be `65`. That actually stumped me and I made mistake while answering. Thanks to @Barmar for catching it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
s='25% 80% 22% 67% 45% 30%'
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i = int( ($i+2) / 5) * 5 "%"} 1' <<< "$s"

25% 80% 20% 65% 45% 30%
```

Comment: That will round down, not to the closest multiple of 5. `23%` will become `20%`, not `25%`.

Comment: Sorry but `67` cannot become `70` because nearest is 65 not 70

Comment: Add 2, not 5. You would use 5 if you wanted the nearest multiple of 10.

Comment: In general, to get the nearest multiple of N, you add N/2.

Comment: You are right and your answer is more correct. Please include this `awk` command in your answer and I will delete this one.

Comment: Thank you @anubhava and Barmar for the discussion and answer!

Comment: Please note that @Barmar was the one who posted correct answer first on rounding part. He should be given credit for getting it right.

Answer (score 1):

`m / 5` always rounds down. You need to add `2` to the number before you divide so that it will get the closest number instead of the always round down.

```
m=23 ; (( m = (m+2)/5, m *= 5)); echo $m
```

Comment: This is great! How can I apply this rounding (up or down) to each of the values in my text file?

Comment: `for m in $(cat filename)`

Comment: The question is about how to do the rounding. Reading the numbers from the file is a separate issue, and has nothing to do with rounding.

Answer (score 1):

Could use perl sub with `e` to evaluate expression in the replacement.

```
perl -pe 's{(\d+)(?=%)}{int(($1+2)/5)*5}ge' file

25,85%,20%,65%,45%,30,20%,2,10%
```